# How to create my DDD entities with Mongodb/Couchdb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, couchdb, domain-driven-design, nosql

I am starting my first project using DDD (using C#) and at this stage I feel we will probably go with MongoDB or maybe CouchDB for the persistence (an ORM like Entity framework seems too much of an overkill for what we want), but saying that I have pretty much zero experience in MongoDB or CouchDB at this stage.

As I am creating my domain I thought about using GUIDS as my IDs for my entities (coming from a relational database world, still having trouble moving away from it).

If I go down this route will I be able to easily plugin in my persistence layer (mongoDB/CouchDB) or would I have to change my domain model (currently my constructors on my entity objects have a string ID as a parameter (which will be the GUID ID)).

JD

Answer (score 3):

With MongoDB you probbly want to have a collection per aggregate root, which means that your aggregate roots needs ids, since they will be the documents in the DB. If you want to keep your domain model free of MongoDB specific code those ids can be strings.

I would not include the ids in the constructor arguments. I would just let them be writable properties. As with an ORM I would consider handling reading and storing of entities via repositories. And keep the MongoDB code in there.

Comment: Thanks. I am still new to DDD and I remember reading that you should not have writable properties (I might be wrong). So with mongoDB, I would just get the document and parse it or would it automagically populate my domain aggregate?

Comment: The official mongo C# driver  can popopulate your entities.